How can I use IKVM in VSCode to convert Java-dependent code into C#?
I installed the necessary libraries using the following configuration:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <NoWarn>8618;8625;8600;8604;8603;8602;8619;8601</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Bogus" Version="34.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="BouncyCastle.Cryptography" Version="2.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="CommandLineParser" Version="2.9.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="gexf-dotnet" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.22.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="HtmlAgilityPack" Version="1.11.50" />
    <PackageReference Include="IKVM" Version="8.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="IKVM.Image.JDK" Version="8.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="IKVM.Maven.Sdk" Version="1.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="IronPython" Version="3.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="JanusGraph.net" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core" Version="3.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Jint" Version="3.23.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MathNet.Numerics" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NuGet.CommandLine" Version="6.6.1">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="PgpCore" Version="5.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="pythonnet" Version="3.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="ZstdNet" Version="1.4.5" />

    <!-- Java Maven repository reference -->
    <MavenRepository Include="https://mvnrepository.com/artifact" />

    <!-- Java Maven references -->
    <MavenReference Include="foo-lib">
      <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
      <artifactId>gremlin-driver</artifactId>
      <version>3.7.2</version>
    </MavenReference>
    
    <MavenReference Include="foo-lib">
      <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
      <artifactId>janusgraph-driver</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </MavenReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

I am trying to convert the following code into C#:
https://docs.janusgraph.org/basics/connecting/java/
import static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal;

GraphTraversalSource g = traversal().withRemote("conf/remote-graph.properties");

I can successfully run this reference without errors:
using org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin;

But this doesn't work:
using org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal;

I can't find traversal() in C#.
I would like to find a way to convert the following Java example code, which currently seems out of reach:
https://docs.janusgraph.org/index-backend/solr/
mgmt = graph.openManagement();
age = mgmt.makePropertyKey("age").dataType(Integer.class).make();
mgmt.buildIndex("verticesByAge", Vertex.class).addKey(age).buildMixedIndex("search");
mgmt.commit();

How can I effectively translate Java sample code like this into C# using IKVM?

Uh. traversal() appears to be a method.
